# Floating mic indicator

Tags: microphone

I have a hardware button for turning the mic on/off. It seems to work essentially as a switch between mic_volume=zero and mic_volume=default. 
When I press the button, Ubuntu/Gnome momentarily displays an overlay ("Internal Microphone") showing the new state.

Is it possible to make a floating indicator that stays up permanently and shows the mic state (perhaps similar to the floating window, but I don't mind).

I would like this so that I can always see whether my mic is on or not. I.e., when using a calling app (say hangouts or skype) I can then switch away from the app, but still see whether my mic is on or not.

Any ideas?

A good start would be to know how to monitor for volume changes.

(Ubuntu 19.10 / Desktop, Gnome)

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.